# Can't Build Cocos2Dx emscripten project

Tags: c++, javascript, html5, cocos2d-x

I need to port a Cocos2D-x project to Web (JS+HTML5). I'm trying to compile cocos2D-x samples using the emscripten project for cocos2d-x, and I've followed this tutorial http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Emscripten_usage without success.

First, I followed the emscripten-specific guide using Linux Mint 15 with this tutorial: 
https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Tutorial

And also on Windows 7 64-bit following this another tutorial: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Using-Emscripten-on-Windows

The emscripten samples worked ok. Then, I downloaded the Cocos2D-x project:

```
git clone https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x.git
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

This version from github, has the "proj.emscripten" project. But, when I try to compile the cocos2D-x project and samples with:

```
make -f Makefile.emscripten -j 8
```

...after compiling several modules, it stops at "cocos2d-x/extensions/proj.emscripten" with this error:

```
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `c:/dev/GitHub/cocos2d-x/CocosDenshion/proj.emscripten'
mingw32-make -C extensions/proj.emscripten all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `c:/dev/GitHub/cocos2d-x/extensions/proj.emscripten'
makefile:12: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `c:/dev/GitHub/cocos2d-x/extensions/proj.emscripten'
Makefile.emscripten:21: recipe for target `all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This happens on both systems: Windows and Linux. I've installed the same version of the required dependencies that apears on those tutorials. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Is there any easier way to get cocos2D-x running on the web without using the cocos2D-x proj.emscripten?

**EDITED: There is an error on cocos2d-x/extensions/proj.emscripten/Makefile file.** Changing the line 11 from this:

```
-I../network
```

...to this:

```
-I../network \
```

...solves this problem. Now compiles some more modules, but now I'm getting compiler errors, like

```
error: no member named 'bind' on namespace 'std'
```

could be a problem with the C++ compiler standards C++0x, C++11...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it!

Mainly there was a problem of typing errors in some files, and the need to specify the C++11 standard in the compile commands. I think that this will be fixed oficially as the project get updated.

These are the steps I done (I asume that previously you have followed the original tutorial from http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Emscripten_usage):

1. Once you have Cocos2D-x downloaded using git, and Emscripten up and runing with all of its dependencies installed, copy all contents from the emscripten folder to (cocos2d-x-root)/external/emscripten
2. Copy the truetype font Arial.ttf (download it, or search it from within your system) to the folder: /Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf (it will not work if you don't have it in that place)
3. Edit cocos2d-x/extensions/proj.emscripten/Makefile

   - Change line 11 from:

   -I../network

   - to:

   -I../network \
4. Edit cocos2d-x/cocos2dx/proj.emscripten/Makefile

   - Change line 145 from:

   CXXFLAGS += -Wno-sequence-point

   - to

   CXXFLAGS += -Wno-sequence-point -std=c++11
5. Edit cocos2d-x/samples/Cpp/TestCpp/proj.emscripten/Makefile

   - Add this new line at 474:

   CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
6. Edit cocos2d-x/cocos2dx/textures/CCTexture2D.cpp

   - Change line 810 from:

   ccTexParams texParams = {m_bHasMipmaps?GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST:GL_NEAREST,GL_NEAREST,GL_NONE,GL_NONE};

   - to:

   ccTexParams texParams = {(GLuint)(m_bHasMipmaps?GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST:GL_NEAREST),(GLuint)GL_NEAREST,(GLuint)GL_NONE,(GLuint)GL_NONE};

   - and line 830 from:

   ccTexParams texParams = {m_bHasMipmaps?GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST:GL_LINEAR,GL_LINEAR,GL_NONE,GL_NONE};

   - to:

   ccTexParams texParams = {(GLuint)(m_bHasMipmaps?GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST:GL_LINEAR),(GLuint)GL_LINEAR,(GLuint)GL_NONE,(GLuint)GL_NONE};

In my case I've got an additional problem (out of memory) when linking the TestCpp project. As I don't need it for now, I simply comment this line at the file cocos2d-x/Makefile.emscripten:

```
#   +$(MAKE) -C samples/Cpp/TestCpp/proj.$(PLATFORM) $@
```

Then, when you run:

```
make -f Makefile.emscripten -j 8
```

inside the cocos2d-x folder, it should compile without any errors, and you will have the .http, .js and .data files in cocos2d-x/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.emscripten/bin/release:

```
HelloCpp.data
HelloCpp.data.js
HelloCpp.js
index.html
```

Remember to copy those files to some web server and run from there, because It will not work in local. And that's all!

Comment: Are you still able to get this to work?